# Ansible - Delegate to - Database Update

Tags: deployment, ansible

Once I have done my deploy I need to update the database structure if any patches need to be applied.

```
My hosts are:

[qa]
qa1
qa2

[prod]
prod1
prod2
```

I only want this to be run once per environment based on which environments are being deployed to.

Scenarios:
- All : db patches should be applied once for each environment e.g. qa1 + prod1
- Prod : db patches should be applied to just production e.g.prod1
- QA : db patches should be applied to just qa e.g.qa1

I can use the `delegate_to` option but how would I cover all scenarios above?

For example if I write: `delegate_to: "{{ groups['prod'][0] }}"` then qa wouldn't get updated etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write separate playbooks to cover the updates of different environments, specifying which one(s) you want in the hosts variable.  For example you would have three playbooks, to cover each permutation of update, each with the following hosts directive set: hosts: qa, hosts: qa:prod, hosts: prod

The other option is to make one playbook to target all groups, hosts: qa:prod, and then use the limit option (--limit/-l) for ansible-playbook to decide which groups to target.